# ajax get file doesn't work on iOS

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

I am developping a webapp and I try to read a file containing data. For now the data file is  on the same server than the webapp, but I plan to deploy the webapp to other servers and to mobile devices (throught phonegap), while keeping the data file on my server and read it securely. So I am looking for a solution that will work in all these cases.
I have tested this code just with the webapp being on the same server as the data file, but it doesn't work for the webbrowser on an iPad (iOS), the  options are empty. Do you know why ?

Thank you

```
    var request = $.ajax({
            url: dbUrl(),
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'text',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("mylogin" + ":" + "mypassword")); },
            success: successCallback
        });

    function dbUrl(){
            return "http://www.mywebsite.fr/webapp/DB.txt";
    }

    function successCallback(data){
        //here I populate "select options".
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a cross domain problem, thanks to @Olavxxx suggested the Jsonp option. I am detailing it here :

```
var request = $.ajax({
            url: dbUrl(),
            jsonpCallback: "callback",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: successCallback,
        });

function dbUrl(){
    return encode_utf8("http://www.mywebsite.fr/webapp/DB.jsonp");
}

function successCallback(data){
    //here I populate "select options".
}
```

And the jsonp file looks like this:

```
callback([
    ["field1","field2"],
    ["DH","Sweet"],
    ["DH2","Switch]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing is first, try:

> dataType: 'jsonp'

if this doesent work and it works on other phones (in browsers) and not on the iPhone, try to utf8encode the URL. I had some issues with QR-codes on Apple devices, that worked on Android. Have had the same issues with FB APPS, if the URL was not utf8 encoded.

If you are using PHP, you can use the utf8encode() function.

If this is not your issue (English is not my native language, so I appologize if I got it wrong): maybe you have a problem with cross domain requests, when moving from your local server? If you use JSONP as above (remember lower case), it should in theory work!

There is also the possibility for whitelisting domains in the header:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.tld

Then there is the JSONP sollution from JQuery :-)

Other resources:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Comment: Thanks @Olavxxx, if I change datatype to jsonp `dataType: 'jsonp'` it doesn't work where it was working with 'text'. My file is a text file, tab separated, but I can change this if necessary, just tell me how, my file is just a table with the first column being the titles : Name \tab property1 \tab property2, ... and the next one is   John Doe, red hair, mustache, ...

Comment: ok thank you, you put me on the right track. But it took me time time to figure how to properly write the jsonp request and file.